# jquery onmouseover effect not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I tried to do something like this:

When I would hover over my button, the text should disappear when my onmouseout, text should display again..

This is my sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KPbDp/)

```
     <div class="frmSnippet fsNoIndent submit">
        <div class="fsInner">

            <button id="requestBooking" class="btn bookingButton" type="submit">Request booking</button>
            <span id="enquireNow" class="btn alt bookingButton" type="submit">Enquire now</span>
    <a href="http://www.paypal.com">
    <span id="payNow" class="btn alt bookingButton">Pay now</span>
    </a>

            <p class="note"><strong>This is a booking request ONLY.</strong> This doesn't guarantee the availability of the property.</p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

                $("#payNow").mouseover(function () {
                  $( this ).find( ".note" ).text( "" );
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
              $( this ).find( ".note" ).text( "mouse out " );
        });

    });
</script>
```

But the problem is I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.note is not a child of payNow use closest and next()

```
$( this ).closest('a').next().text( "" );
```

or just use

```
$('.note').text("");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/KPbDp/2/)

Comment: thanks, can it possibly just remove the class .note and when onmouseout add again the class .note?

Comment: In your update, when onmouseout again, the existing text i.e. "This is ..." should reappear again, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/KPbDp/3/)

```
$(this).closest('a').next("p.note").text("mouse out ");
```

Read

http://api.jquery.com/next/

http://api.jquery.com/closest/